# Apostrophecms 2.86 versions upgrade issue

Tags: upgrade, apostrophe-cms

I am getting below error while trying to upgrade apostrophe version to 2.86:

> ⚠️  doc type trash contains unarranged field(s): title, tags, published, trash, slug, type, orphan.
>   Arrange all of your fields with arrangeFields, using meaningful group labels.
>   https://apos.dev/arrange-fields
>
> This warning appears only once to save space. Pass --all-unarranged-fields
>   on the command line to see the warning for all affected modules.

I have also added `APOS_NO_MIGRATE: 1` into deployment configuration. Please help! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is a warning, not an error. Have you tried doing as recommended in the message? Are there any actual errors after this preventing your site from operating?

Comment: Some issues relating to this message have been improved, so it is recommended that you upgrade to the current release (2.90.0). But it is not an error and should not prevent your site from working. If it does you need to be specific about the problem.

Comment: Thanks Tom! By updating the version to `2.86` and adding/updating `arrangeFields` in the widgets/pieces schema where these grouping were missing, this issue got resolved now. Thank you once again!